# base class methods for classes whose base class cannot be modified?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am using entity framework to generate a 'CClass' entity as below:

```
public partial class CClass: EntityObject
{
    #region Factory Method

    #region Primitive Properties
}
```

My rest of the partial class implementation is

```
public partial class CClass : IDemoralize
{
    public Value xValue { get; set; }

    public void IDemoralize.Demoralize()
    {
        // implementation

    }
    public void IDemoralize.Demoralize(Func<IDemoralize, bool> CustomDemoralization)
    {
        bool success = CustomDemoralization(this);

        if (!success)
            throw new ApplicationException();
    }

    public void IDemoralize.WriteModel()
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public void IDemoralize.WriteModel(Func<IDemoralize, bool> Write)
    {
        bool success = Write(this);
        if (!success)
            throw new ApplicationException();
    }
}
```

Now since two methods listed below here does have common implementation across the whole design I want to move them to a base class called DemoralizeBase, so if code needs change then the consistency becomes manageable.

```
// in DemoralizeBase 
public void Demoralize(Func<IDemoralize, bool> CustomDemoralization)
{
    //implementation
}

public void WriteModel(Func<IDemoralize, bool> Write)
{
    // implementation
}
```

Is there a way to do this or I should go with the existing design?

Comment: You could work around it with a 2-level inheritance

Comment: DemoralizeBase can inherit from EntityObject. CClass then inherits from DemoralizeBase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write those as extension methods:

```
public static class Demoralize {
    public static void Demoralize(this IDemoralize obj,
         Func<IDemoralize, bool> CustomDemoralization) {...}
    public static void WriteModel(this IDemoralize obj,
         Func<IDemoralize, bool> Write) {...}
}
```

This will then work *as though* it were an instance method, i.e.

```
var foo = new CClass();
foo.Demoralize(...);
```

One thing to watch: when calling extension methods on the **current** instance, the `this.` (which is usually optional) is ***required***, i.e.

```
Demoralize(...); // does not work
this.Demoralize(...); // works
```

Comment: Alternatively you can also call the method directly and pass the instance: "Demoralize.Demoralize(yourCClassInstance, ...);" - tho I prefer the syntax described in the answer. Also note that the instance passed to your extension method can be null.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for some **dependency injection** here.
IDemoralize defines 4 methods, 2 of them have common implementation across your framework.
What I would do is: extract a new interface from IDemoralize, and add a dependency to an object that implements that interface into CClass.

```
public interface IDemoralizeBase
{
    void Demoralize(Func<IDemoralize, bool> CustomDemoralization);
    void WriteModel(Func<IDemoralize, bool> Write);
}
```

Add an object IDemoralizeBase to CClass, and define a constructor that lets you inject the dependency

```
public class CClass : IDemoralize
{
    public IDemoralizeBase MyDemoralizer {get; private set;}

    public CClass(IDemoralizeBase basicDemoralizer)
    {
        MyDemoralizer = basicDemoralizer;
    }

    public void Demoralize(Func<IDemoralize, bool> CustomDemoralization)
    {
        MyDemoralizer.Demoralize(CustomDemoralization);
    }

    public void WriteModel(Func<IDemoralize, bool> Write)
    {
        MyDemoralizer.WriteModel(Write);
    }
}
```

This will let you create one or *n* classes that implement IDemoralizeBase, so that, in case you get some special implementation in some special case, you can inject a special dependency.

Cheers,

Raphael